# error in running auto.arima function

Tags: time, series, forecasting, stock

I am downloading some stock's daily close data using quantmod package:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
library(forecast)

date <- as.Date("2014-11-01")

getSymbols("SBIN.BO",from = date )

close <- SBIN.BO[, 4]

dygraph(close)

dat <- data.frame(date = index(SBIN.BO),SBIN.BO)

acf1 <- acf(close)
```

**When I tried to execute auto arima function from forecast package:**

```
fit <- auto.arima(close, seasonal=FALSE, xreg=fourier(close, K=4))
```

**I encountered the following error:**

```
Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:length(x)) : 
  K must be not be greater than period/2
```

So I want to know why there is this error? Did I do any mistake in writing code, which based upon tutorials available on Rob's website/blogs...

Comment: `close` should have a `ts` attribute with frequency information. Use the `ts()` function.

Comment: I tried :   close <- ts(SBIN.BO[, 4], frequency = 1) and also fit <- auto.arima(ts(close, frequency = 1), seasonal=FALSE, xreg=fourier(ts(close, frequency = 1), K=4))
none worked.. got same error as above.

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/ to see how to set the frequency attribute. Setting it 1 makes no sense with seasonal data.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Will go through that.